# How to show document using a hash mark

Tags: java, html, javafx

I'm using a Hyperlink to open an HTML file in the default browser:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("apple");
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/ExampleUser/Documents/fruits.html");
link.setOnAction(evt -> {
            getHostServices().showDocument(path.toString());
});
```

Which works fine. However, I want to open the document on a specific point using the available IDs and immediately jump on "C:/Users/ExampleUser/Documents/fruits.html#apple". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the `showDocument()` method directly and add the anchor:

```
getHostServices().showDocument("file:///C:/Users/ExampleUser/Documents/fruits.html#apple");
```

But you have to add the URI scheme, otherwise the method will open the path

> file://C:/Users/ExampleUser/Documents/fruits.html%23apple

which is obviously not the URI you want to open.

Comment: This actually manages to load the file correctly, but it does not lead me to the `<div id="apple">`. However, typing "file://C:/Users/ExampleUser/Documents/fruits.html#apple" in the address bar works as expected.

Comment: I tested it again (on Ubuntu) and it worked for me in Firefox as well as in Chrome. Maybe you have to close all tabs with that site opened before, or clear you browser cache, because sometimes the scroll position is cached and preferred to the anchor tags.